# X will not start while installing Ubuntu 13.10 on an ASUS N550JV

Tags: system-installation, xorg, asus

I've been trying to install Ubuntu from a live usb on my ASUS N550JV-CN270H, of which the DVD Drive has been replaced by an SSD (Crucial M500 480GB).

When I select **Try Ubuntu** in GRUB the normal loading screen appears, but the screen gets stuck on the part where all 5 dots are filled in for a while.

After trying to boot with `nomodeset` I can switch to a TTY and all I have found out so far is that X doesn't start. When trying to manually start it with `startx`, I see `(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.`

What should I try next?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a real answer or a solution, but I could install in OEM mode with `nomodeset`. Afterwards, I used this `xorg.conf` to force my resolution:

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Default Screen"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Depth 24
Modes "1920x1080"
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Module"
Load "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "Default Device"
Driver "intel"
EndSection
```